# CSS two columns layout

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LFvlp

HTML

```
   <div class="entry-content">
  I’m not the only one in the family having a weakness for interiors. I think I received the microbe from my parents. Although our style is different on the first sight, there are still a lot of things we have in common. We both love contemporary design in combination with vintage. Also I have the love for design classics in my veins because of them.

The biggest difference is that the living room is a dark and cozy cave. But the design classics give the space that extra touch. Every time when I look at those, I discover a new detail. That makes this living room a real inspiration for me.


  <div class="post-tags">
    Chair: Hans J. Wegner, coffee table: Eames 
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
 .entry-content {
         -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
         column-count: 2;

         -webkit-column-gap: 30px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         -moz-column-gap: 30px; /* Firefox */
         column-gap: 30px;
     }

.post-tags {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

As you can see in the codepen I have two css columns. Now I want the 'post-tags' div to always be on the same height as the last line of the first alinea. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you need the first div in first column and second div in second column?

Comment: Why don't you just send `post-tags` div to the outside?

Comment: No, I want the second column to be exactly the same height as the first column (or a little bit shorter is also good). Now, as you can see, the second column is a little longer as the first one (mostly when i make my screen smaller)

Comment: Because it needs to be in the second column

Comment: Try [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EFsBw)

Comment: reduce the margin-top of the post-tags div to say 5px - http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/srilx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert another element after `.post-tags`: This forces the renderer to take the `margin-top` into account when calculating the columns.

HTML: `<div class="colfix">0</div>` (Can't be empty)

CSS: `.colfix{ visibility: hidden; }`

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dmwjc